# Bootstrap modal not displaying content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display an external content (another page) modal over my index.html but it's not working.

Modal is displayed with header and footer but the modal body is not loading the external page or anything else inside of it.

I created some tags inside modal body (headings, paragraphs, ...) but nothing is displayed.

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.openPopup').on('click', function () {
            var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
            $('.modal-body').load(dataURL, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    ...
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div id="about-me">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="about-me-title">Título</h1>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row about-me-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <a class="openPopup" href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="./modal.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block01.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block02.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row about-me-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block03.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block04.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row about-me-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block01.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding black-hover">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/block03.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row decription-row"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
<footer class="footer">
    <p>@ 2018</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: We'd need to see more code, like how you're trying to populate the modal body.

Comment: Are you accessing index.html from localhost (http protocol)? If not (file protocol), Chromium based browsers will block access to "external" files via AJAX. Take a look at the browser's console to see if there is any error message.

Comment: @Triby great man! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Triby add an answer if you want for me to close the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium based browsers blocks access to files via AJAX if you access from file protocol, so, just open your page from a web server (http protocol).